# DESeq2 and EdgeR

Tags: deseq2, edger, homework

I am new to using both DESeq2 and EdgeR in Bioconductor used for transforming my RNA expression data.

However, I am struggling to understand their specific purpose, differences between them and underlying theory. The information is required for a thesis with an imminent deadline

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @noor-fatimah, your question seems quite broad and not tied to a specific problem; are you able to make your question more specific, or give some more information on what you've already found out? Have you, for example, read the user's guides for [EdgeR](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/edgeR/inst/doc/edgeRUsersGuide.pdf) and [DESeq2](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/DESeq2/inst/doc/DESeq2.html)?

Comment: i need to do proximal vs distal comparison, for that i need to convert my csv file it contains single gene id data multiple time i need to narrow it down to one how can i do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question has been answered very well here:
https://www.biostars.org/p/284775/

If you want to go deeper perhaps you can look at this paper by Li et al.
https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13059-022-02648-4
where they argue that for large scale datasets (multiple conditions) both of these methods are not optimal and instead suggests using Wilcoxon rank-sum test to decrease chances of FDRs.

Best,

av

Comment: i need to do proximal vs distal comparison, for that i need to convert my csv file it contains single gene id data multiple time i need to narrow it down to one how can i do that